# Angular 8 and FormArrays how to initialize drop down list to select the initial value coming with the array

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am having a drop down list where user can select multiple items from it, and items will be appended the into an array `selectedInvoicesArray`:

```
Object.keys(selectedInvoices).forEach((key, index)=>{
   this.selectedInvoicesArray.push(this.invoicesList.filter(res => {
        return res.invoice_id == selectedInvoices[key] 
   }));
})
```

At the html side, we have a `*ngFor` to loop over `selectedInvoicesArray` array and display info of each index into a div.

What I need is to display a drop down list having `Active` and `Inactive` as options, where the original value is selected once the section of each item is displayed on the component, and then user can change the status.

The only method to do that is by using `FormArray`.

So I did the following:

I created a form group containing a form array:

```
 <form [formGroup]="updateStatusForm">
   <mat-form-field *ngFor="let select of selectedInvoicesArray; let i = index">
    <mat-select [formControlName]="i">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let status of invoiceStatuses" [value]="status.id">{{status.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

Then, I created the formGroup script:

```
updateStatusForm: FormGroup;

createUpdateStatusForm(){
    this.updateStatusForm = this.fb.group({
      'statusesControl': new FormControl('')
    })
  }
```

And I called `createUpdateStatusForm()` each time a new array is being pushed into `selectedInvoicesArray`:

```
Object.keys(selectedInvoices).forEach((key, index)=>{
      this.selectedInvoicesArray.push(this.invoicesList.filter(res => {
        return res.invoice_id == selectedInvoices[key]

      }));
      this.createUpdateStatusForm()
    })
```

As you can see in the image, the drop down list is empty. I need to set it to the initial value coming from the array.

[image]

The `*ngFor` that is iterating over `selectedInvoicesArray` is as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let invoice of selectedInvoicesArray;let i = index;">
```

And as an example:

```
<div>
     Description: {{invoice[0].description}}
</div>
```

When I push 2 or more arrays into `selectedInvoicesArray`, in each section I see 2 or more drop down lists:

[image]

But I am not able to set the initial value of each generated form array to display the original status coming with the array which named `is_active`.

**EDIT**

What I tried next, is to loop over `selectedInvoicesArray` and set the value of each generated form array:

```
Object.keys(this.selectedInvoicesArray).forEach(key=>{
      console.log(this.selectedInvoicesArray[key].invoices[0])

this.createUpdateStatusForm(this.selectedInvoicesArray[key].invoices[0].is_active);
})
```

And:

```
createUpdateStatusForm(status_id){
    this.updateStatusForm = this.fb.group({
      'statusesControl': new FormControl(status_id)
    })
  }
```

But I've got the following error:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at FormGroupDirective.addControl

Comment: `this.createUpdateStatusForm()` , it will create new form-group instance each time.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda yes. I am trying to fix it. But nothing is working.

Comment: can you explain in short of what you are trying to do? You have one form-group, inside you have one form-array which you want to show in dropdown ma-select?

Comment: Might not be the exact solution, but your first chunk of code `this.selectedInvoicesArray.push(this.invoicesList.filter(res => {return res.invoice_id == selectedInvoices[key] }));` will push an array, not just one item. So even though you're filtering `invoicesList` down to just one item (that's what I'm understanding), `selectedInvoicesArray` is going to look like `[[invoice]]` rather than `[invoice]`. Try changing filter to find, which specifically returns the first item it finds given the predicate you pass in. Filter returns an array containing the items based on the predicate.

Comment: @nonexistent I will try now

Comment: A mat select can be used with **multiple**, and "feeded" by a FormControl, not by a FormArray. Yes, the FormControl store an array, but it's NOT a formArray, check the example about multiple selection: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection

Comment: @Eliseo the form array is not on select multiple, but on select single value. What I really want is to display for each pushed array, a mat-select having default value the arrays status, and the user can change it later to different value.